# using function object though function pointer is required

Tags: c++, function-pointers, functor

I have to use some legacy code expecting a function pointer, let's say:

```
void LEGACY_CODE(int(*)(int))
{
    //...
}
```

However the functionality I have is within a functor:

```
struct X
{
    Y member;       
    X(Y y) : member(y)
    {}

    int operator()(int)
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

How should I modify/wrap class `X` so that `LEGACY_CODE` can access the functionality within `X::operator()(int)` ?

Comment: We need an automatic "member function as callback" question solver.

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes no sense. **Whose** operator do you want to call?

```
X a, b, c;

LEGACY_CODE(???); // what -- a(), b(), or c()?
```

So, in short, you cannot. The member function `X::operator()` is not a property of the class alone, but rather it is tied to an *object instance* of type `X`.

Search this site for "member function" and "callback" to get an idea of the spectrum of possible approaches for related problems.

---

The crudest, and quite possibly not-safe-for-use, workaround to providing a free function would go like this:

```
X * current_X;  // ugh, a global
int dispatch(int n) { current_X->operator()(n); }

int main()
{
  X a;
  current_X = &a;
  LEGACY_CODE(dispatch);
}
```

You can see where this is going...

Comment: I'm pretty sure he knows how member functions work. He was asking if there's a way to make the legacy code compatible with the new code.

Comment: @PaulManta: So what. A class isn't a magic generalization of a function, and if the OP is confused about that, then this answer makes sense. If the OP knows that, on the other hand, she should have been explicit about which instance she wants to use.

Answer (score 0):

A simple wrapper function looks like:

```
int wrapperfunction(int i) {
    Functor f(params);
    return f(i);
}
```

If you want to be able to pass the parameters to the functor itself, the simplest way is to sneak them in using (brr) a global variable:

```
Functor functorForWrapperfunction;
int wrapperfunction(int i) {
    functorForWrapperfunction(i);
}
// ...
void clientCode() {
    functorForWrapperfunction = Functor(a,b,c);
    legacyCode(wrapperfunction);
}
```

You can wrap it with a class with a static method and a static member if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one compile-time solution. Depending on what you need, this might be a too limited solution for you.

```
template<typename Func, int Param>
int wrapper(int i)
{
    static Func f(Param);
    return f(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A thread-safe version under the restriction that the legacy code is not called with different parameters in a thread.

IMHO, one cannot get rid of global storage.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>

class AA
    {
    public:
        AA (int i) : i_(i) {}
        void  operator()(int j) const {
            static boost::mutex m; // do not garble output
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
            std::cout << " got " << j << " on thread " <<  i_ << std::endl; 
            Sleep(200); } 
        int i_;
    };

// LEGACY
void legacy_code(void (*f)(int), int i) {   (*f)(i);    }

// needs some global storage through
 boost::thread_specific_ptr<AA> global_ptr;

void func_of_thread(int j)
    {
    AA *a = global_ptr.get();
    a->operator()(j);
    }

void worker(int i)
{
 global_ptr.reset(new AA(i));
 for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
     legacy_code(func_of_thread,j);
    }


int main()
    {
    boost::thread worker1(worker,1) , worker2(worker,2);
    worker1.join(); worker2.join();
    return 0;
    }
```